# Animation package from Assert Store not working probably with Unity Model/Custom Model?

Tags: unity, animation, models

I downloaded the animation pack from here:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25794
The assert contains a fbx file, which contains a bunch of animations.

Then in Animator window I added a State and transitions between states and have set the Motion in the inspector of the state.
Then I look at the preview in Animator's inspector with it original Model, the animation works properly:

[image: attachFull147746]

If I apply Unity Model or my custom Model in the preview, its became:

[image]

Why is that?  How can I fix it?
Or did I use it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just notice the animation package Model is set as Generic, in order to match the Unity Model its has to set as humanoid as well.
Now is working perfectly fine!